# How to calculate time in excel?

Tags: excel, time

I have to compare the time elapsed between the time of the call and the arrival at the scene for a project. I have two columns with the format : 
2013-09-01 10:51:00.000
I used this formula

```
=INT(H2-F2)&" days, "&INT(((H2-F2)-INT(H2-F2))*24)&" hours, "&INT((((H2-F2)*24)-INT((H2-F2)*24))*60)&" min"
```

But i get an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your formula works for me (assuming H2 >= F2) but to simplify, you can get same result with this version

`=INT(H2-F2)&" days, "&TEXT(H2-F2,"h"" hours, ""m"" min""")`

If your formula or this one doesn't work, I suggest that you might have invalid time values, check that you don't have extra spaces or characters

see screenshot

[image]

Comment: The previous formula gave me 'value error', this one does not even work :(

Comment: I added a screenshot, it shows both formulas working for me - column I is your formula and column J is mine. Like I say, you may not have valid time values. TEXT function may need adjusting for non-English excel, e.g. if h for hours and m for minutes is different

Comment: Note that in my example the date/time values in columns H and F are text-formatted. Both formulas will work OK with valid date/time values or text formatted date/time values.....but if there are extra characters or spaces that will make the formula fail

Comment: still error with the formula, and i think it is because of the ''